# Maximum Product of Three Numbers

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

I am trying to solve this problem from [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-product-of-three-numbers/description/), going to copy here for convenience

```
Given an integer array, find three numbers whose product is maximum and output the maximum product.

Example 1:
Input: [1,2,3]
Output: 6
Example 2:
Input: [1,2,3,4]
Output: 24
Note:
The length of the given array will be in range [3,104] and all elements are in the range [-1000, 1000].
Multiplication of any three numbers in the input won't exceed the range of 32-bit signed integer.
```

After (unsuccessfully) trying it, I googled the solution and this works

```
class Solution(object):
    def maximumProduct(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        ans = pa = pb = pc = None
        na = nb = 0x7FFFFFFF
        for n in nums:
            if n > pa:
                pa, pb, pc = n, pa, pb
            elif n > pb:
                pb, pc = n, pb
            elif n > pc:
                pc = n
            if n < na:
                na, nb = n, na
            elif n < nb:
                nb = n
        return max(ans, pa * na * nb, pa * pb * pc)
```

I understand the logic except why na and nb are assigned a value of 0x7FFFFFFF. It looks like it is int32's maximum value. Can someone help me explain the significance of this number and why it is used here? (I would have used 1001 instead)

Comment: `ans` is never changed from its initial constant value - why? I don't think 0x7FFF_FFFF is of any significance except that it's the maximum possible number, and therefore is guaranteed to be overwritten with the numbers from the array. It's arguably better than 1001 because even someone who hadn't read the problem description properly would be able to see that it's the maximum possible number. That's all there is to it, I reckon.

Comment: The code also looks like it was written by a Java programmer; the class serves no purpose.

Comment: Basically, the answer comes from one of three cases: the three largest positive numbers, the three largest *negative* numbers, or the two largest negative numbers and the largest positive number. `na` and `nb` are just initialized to some version of infinity to make the comparisons work the first time.

Comment: @chepner thanks for responding, leetcode gives basic barebones for expected code so that's why the class. However, I agree it serves no purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pseudocode, `0x7FFFFFFF` would be rendered as infinity (and `None`, as minus infinity). The proof of correctness is a lemma to the effect that the three numbers with the greatest product can be found among the greatest three and the least two. Plus/minus infinity serves as a sentinel value for the min/max two/three values, to be replaced shortly by actual values once the first three have been scanned.

`1001` would work as well.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the @David Eisenstat answer, few additional comments:

- Considering `None` as minus infinity is something that will work on python2 but it'll raise an exception in python3, for instance:

> In early Python, the decision was made that the comparison of any two
>   objects was legal and would return a consistent result. So objects of
>   different types will compare according to an ordering on their types
>   (an implementation dependent, unspecified, but consistent ordering),
>   and objects of the same type will be compared according to rules that
>   make sense for that type.
>
> Other implementations have the right to compare an integer and None
>   differently, but on a specific implementation, the result will not
>   change.
>
> Python 3 will raise an exception on such comparisons.

- You're correct, `0x7FFFFFFF` would be the equivalent to the max signed int, `sys.maxsize == 0x7FFFFFFF`
- In python2 you can make the next comparisons, both `0x7FFFFFFF>(1000*1000*1000)` and `None<-(1000*1000*1000)` are `True`, so using 0x7FFFFFFF as upper bound and None as lower bound is just fine, although other bounds would be correct as well
- That said, I'd suggest you refactor that code to make it work also in python3 :)

Answer (score 2):

Taking the following example: [-999, -999, 100, 200, 300], the answer is to take -999, -999 and 300 (and not simply the product of the 3 largest numbers).

As a consequence, you need to store:

- the 3 largest numbers (`pa`, `pb`, `pc`)
- the 2 smallest numbers (`na`, `nb`)

The result is the greatest value between `pa * na * nb` and `pa * pb * pc`.

`0x7FFFFFFF` is just a very big number used to find the smallest values. Since the greatest possible value is 1000, 1000 could have been used instead.

Similarly, the author used None to initialize `pa`, `pb` and `pc`. The author could have used -1000 instead.

Answer (score -1):

Although this **doesn't actually provide an answer to the actual question**, it's an alternative that **goes around the scenario that was brought up**, and achieves the same (final) goal (it's more elegant, but slower - especially for large lists). 
It works on both *Python 2* and *Python 3* (where *reduce* could also be replaced by *itertools.accumulate*), and makes use of:

- [[Python 2.Docs]: Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#built-in-functions) (*max*, *reduce*)
- [[Python 2.Docs]: operator - Standard operators as functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#module-operator) (*mul*)
- [[Python 2.Docs]: itertools - Functions creating iterators for efficient looping](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) (*combinations*)

> ```py
> >>> import itertools
> >>> import operator
> >>> 
> >>> l = [1, 9, 0, -5, 7, 2, 4]
> >>>
> >>> def max_prod(seq, count=3):
> ...     return max(reduce(operator.mul, item) for item in itertools.combinations(seq, count))
> ...
> >>> max_prod(l)
> 252
> ```

which is: ***9 * 7 * 4***.

Comment: I think you should also say that it's more elegant but much slower if the list is big. However, the statement says that the length of the list is lower than 104, so it's perfectly acceptable (less than 200 000 combinations).